# Prepending to a Scala Iterator -- timeout?

Tags: scala

I want to prepend a new iterator to my existing iterator.

1. How can I prepend a new Iterator to an existing Iterator?
2. Why does my code cause my REPL to hang?

The following hangs indefinitely in my REPL:

```
scala> var i = Seq(1).iterator
var i: Iterator[Int] = <iterator>

scala> i = Seq(2).iterator ++ i
// mutated i

scala> i.next()
val res0: Int = 2

scala> i.next()
. . .
```

Note that the following works, but this is an append not a prepend:

```
var i = Seq(1).iterator
i = i ++ Seq(2).iterator
i.next()
i.next()
```

This also works, but materializes the entire iterator which I cannot do:

```
var i = Seq(1).iterator
i = (Seq(2) ++ i.toSeq).iterator
i.next()
i.next()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have to mix mutability to mutability for your use case? Can't you just create a new variable?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, I do need to extend this same variable. IteratorChain works fine, but it requires conversion to a Java iterator.

Comment: Care to explain what is the meta-problem you are trying to solve? I am pretty sure there is an easy way to solve this in an immutable way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply speaking, it hangs because you have there an infinite loop. In the line where you think you are merging iterators, you are actually referencing the new `i` (laziness) and not the initial value of `i`.

You can get over that by introducing a new var as Luis Miguel pointed out

```
var i = Seq(1).iterator
var j = i
i = Seq(2).iterator ++ j
i.next()
i.next()
```

so that should do the trick. Hope it helps and is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks! This confuses me a little -- shouldn't `j` just be another reference to `i`? If I had to do something like `val j = i.clone()` that would be intuitive, but I'm a little unsure why this works...

Comment: No because iterators you have here are immutable